# Why does a distinct query return duplicate values?

Tags: prolog

Here is the program:

```
sibling(joe, mary).
sibling(joe, bob).
person(P) :- distinct(sibling(P, _); sibling(_, P)).
```

Here is the query:

```
person(P).
```

I would expect to get 3 names, instead I get 4.

Comment: The problem is that it uses the `Goal` as the pattern to match here.

Comment: You might try `setof(X, Y^(sibling(X,Y); sibling(Y,X)), Sibs).` which yields `Sibs = [bob, joe, mary]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: Prolog keeps track of all variables that come out of the goal, including don't cares (`_`).

The problem is that you introduce free variables here, that are *not* distinct. Indeed, as is specified in the documentation of [**`distinct/1`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=distinct/1). The above is functionally equivalent to:

> ```
> distinct(Goal) :-
>     findall(Goal, Goal, List),
>     list_to_set(List, Set),
>     member(Goal, Set).
> ```

Now if we make a simple call with `sibling(P, _)`, we get:

```
?- Goal = sibling(P, _), distinct(Goal).
Goal = sibling(joe, mary),
P = joe ;
Goal = sibling(joe, bob),
P = joe.
```

or with a goal with a logical "or":

```
?- Goal = (sibling(P, _); sibling(_, P)), distinct(Goal).
Goal =  (sibling(joe, mary);sibling(_4908, joe)),
P = joe ;
Goal =  (sibling(joe, bob);sibling(_4908, joe)),
P = joe ;
Goal =  (sibling(mary, _4904);sibling(joe, mary)),
P = mary ;
Goal =  (sibling(bob, _4904);sibling(joe, bob)),
P = bob.
```

So as you can see, `Goal` is unified twice: once with `sibling(joe, mary)`, and once with `sibling(joe, bob)`. The uniqness filter will not have any effect, since `mary` is not the same as `bob`.

We can however define a helper predicate here, to get rid of these variables, like:

```
person(P) :-
    sibling(P, _).
person(P) :-
    sibling(_, P).
```

and then we can query with:

```
?- Goal = person(P), distinct(Goal).
Goal = person(joe),
P = joe ;
Goal = person(mary),
P = mary ;
Goal = person(bob),
P = bob.
```

or without using a `Goal` variable:

```
?- distinct(person(P)).
P = joe ;
P = mary ;
P = bob.
```

Comment: Thank you! Does it make sense to do something like this? `person2(P) :- sibling(P, _).
person2(P) :- sibling(_, P).
person(P) :- distinct(person2(P)).`

Comment: @stenci: yes, although one usually underscores instead of `2`, so `person_(P) :- sibling(P, _)`, etc. (but that is of course only a convention).